# Cannot load spark json dataframe into a hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert a dataframe into a json object and load it into a json table.

Below is the code

Create the table

```
spark.sql("""create table IF NOT EXISTS user_tech.tests (
Z struct<A:string, 
 B:string,
 C:string>
)
stored as orc """)

import org.apache.spark.sql._
```

Initial data frame

```
val df = Seq((1,2,3),(2,3,4)).toDF("A", "B", "C")    


val jsonColumns = df.select("A", "B", "C")
```

Converting it into json

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finalDF = jsonColumns.select(to_json(struct(col("A"), col("B"), col("C")))).as("Z")
```

Insert the rows into the table

```
finalDF.registerTempTable("test")

spark.sql(""" select * from test """).show()

spark.sql("""Insert into  user_tech.tests select * from test""")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'test.`structstojson(named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), A, NamePlaceholder(), B, NamePlaceholder(), C))`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast StringType to StructType(StructField(guid,StringType,true), StructField(sessionid,StringType,true));;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following statement.

```
val finalDF = jsonColumns.select(to_json(struct(col("A"), col("B"), col("C")))).as("Z")
```

A quick validation of the above DataFrame will make you understand that you are creating a single column of String type.

```
scala> finalDF.show
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|structtojson(named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), A, NamePlaceholder(), B, NamePlaceholder(), C))|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                         {"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}|
|                                                                         {"A":2,"B":3,"C":4}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala> finalDF.printSchema
root
 |-- structtojson(named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), A, NamePlaceholder(), B, NamePlaceholder(), C)): string (nullable = true)
```

And when you try to insert from Temp table registered on finalDF, the schema doesn't match and you got the exception.

Following should work for you.

```
spark.sql("""create table IF NOT EXISTS tests (
Z struct<A:string, 
 B:string,
 C:string>
)
stored as orc """)


import org.apache.spark.sql._

val df = Seq((1,2,3),(2,3,4)).toDF("A", "B", "C")    

val jsonColumns = df.select("A", "B", "C")

jsonColumns.registerTempTable("tmp")

spark.sql("""Insert into tests select struct(*) from tmp""")
```

You can see the data using the following statement.

```
spark.sql("select * from tests").show


+-------+
|      Z|
+-------+
|[1,2,3]|
|[1,2,3]|
|[2,3,4]|
|[2,3,4]|
+-------+
```

Hope that helps!